# Unable to Generate Signed APK in Android Studio gives me error with proguard-rules.txt not found?

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Hi I am new to Android Studio to build and generate signed apk file. I tried alot to generate APK file but I am stuck on this.

I found some links to generate signed apk file, please check below.

http://xda-university.com/as-a-developer/getting-started-android-studio    http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Generating_a_Signed_Release_APK_File_in_Android_Studio

I followed same way but in that process it is not showing Run Proguard option to check and generate apk file, please see below.

[image]

[image]

Please check my below code Here:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:17'
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.wasl.properties"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 17
        versionCode 8
        versionName "2.1"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
 compile files('libs/commons-codec-1.4.jar')
 compile files('libs/FlurryAnalytics_3.3.0.jar')
 compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
 compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.8.5-with-sources.jar')
 compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
}
```

Please help on this , Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

In your `build.gradle` file, you have the default proguard processing step enabled for your release build. The build process is attempting to run proguard (that's the `minifyEnabled` line) and searching for the files specified on the line below (which, according to your error message, don't exist).

If you don't want to run proguard (and at this stage, I presume you don't) you should delete the contents of the `release` build type:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Adam, while attempting to release signed build with run proguard is searching for the proguard files which dosn't exists  then gives me error proguard-rules.txt not found in specified location path. How can i fix this and how can i release signed build.